# operator>> on a tied tuple with std::ignore

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have stumbled upon the following problem while designing a 'generic' reader:

The following Code works perfectly fine (you need c++1z support to compile as it uses constexpr if, but with minor modifications it should also compile with c++11):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template<int N, class tuple_type>
struct fill_tuple {
    static void write(std::vector<std::string>& container, tuple_type& tuple)
    {
        // use operator >> to fill the N-1'th member of the tuple
        std::stringstream(container[N - 1]) >> std::get<N - 1>(tuple);
        if constexpr(N > 1){ // Continue if there are till fields to read
            fill_tuple<N - 1, tuple_type>::write(container, tuple);
        }
    }
};

template<class tuple_type>
void read (std::vector<std::string>& container, tuple_type obj){
    fill_tuple<std::tuple_size<tuple_type>::value, tuple_type>::write(container, obj);
}

struct some_data {
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
    char d;

    auto content() {
        return std::tie(a,b,c,d);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> some_strings = {"a","b","c","d"};
    // Read some_strings into some_data
    some_data foo;
    read(some_strings, foo.content());
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, any bound checks (such as tuple_size <= container size) are omitted.

If i wanted to parse a struct that only has members a,b and d using a container with a size of 4, my intuition was to simply rewrite `std::tie(a,b,c,d)` to `std::tie(a,b,std::ignore,d)`.

This, however, fails as `std::ignore` (or gcc's implementation) does not seem to have a `operator>>` function. 
I have already tried checking against `std::ignore` using `std::is_same`: `std::is_same<typename std::remove_reference<typename std::tuple_element<N - 1,tuple_type>::type>::type, std::ignore>::value`, but this also fails.

My question is: Is there a way to check against std::ignore, or even better, replace it entirely without relying prior modifications to the container vector?

Comment: `std::ignore` is "object-like", not "type-like". Try to put `decltype` around it.

Comment: "The following Code works perfectly fine" - really, even without ";" after struct declaration?

Comment: Sorry @EdgarRokyan, i have edited the code to actually compile.

Comment: "without relying prior modifications to the container vector" what do you mean ?

Comment: @Incomputable - IMHO, your comment should be an answer

Comment: @max66, let me search for some references and I'll post it as answer.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I do not want to preprocess `std::vector<std::string> container`. That is, i do not want to simply remove the 'c' element from `some_strings` in the given example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> replace it entirely without relying prior modifications to the container vector?

instead of using `is_same`, you may just overload against `decltype(ignore)`; in C++17:

```
template<typename T>
void read_element( std::string const& s, T& t ) { std::stringstream{s} >> t; }
void read_element( std::string const&, decltype(std::ignore) const& ) { /*do nothing*/ }

std::apply( [&](auto&... args)
        {
            auto it = some_vector_of_strings.begin();
            ( read_element( *it++, args ), ... );
        }, tuple );
```

the same idea applies to your C++11 code as well.

Comment: Tag based dispatch still works, lol. Despite being more cumbersome to deal with.

Comment: @incomputable yep, tag dispatching may be even more appropriate if more complex read_element logic is required. That said, I believe the OP original intention was to use *if constexpr* here.

Comment: I feel somewhat ashamed that i did not come up with this myself. Anyway, i really like your answer, but for the record, it needs to be `decltype(std::ignore)&` in my specific case.

Comment: @patrickklein you're right, even better *decltype(std::ignore) const&*; fixed

Answer (score 1):

As state in comment, `std::ignore` is not a type, but an object, you have to use `decltype(std::ignore)` to get the type.

```
template <typename T>
void read_simple(const std::string& s, T& obj)
{
    std::stringstream(s) >> obj;   
}

void read_simple(const std::string&, const decltype(std::ignore)&) {}

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename Tuple>
void read(const std::vector<std::string>& container,
          Tuple&& obj,
          std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    (read_simple(container[Is], std::get<Is>(obj)), ...);   
}

template <typename Tuple>
void read(const std::vector<std::string>& container, Tuple&& obj)
{
    read(container,
         obj,
         std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>());
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dca85f61b04a6c7)

Comment: for the record, AFAIK the type of ignore may not be copyable, so it should be passed by ref for portability sake ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes: fixed.